Blazor wasm deployment to subdomain - api calls blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
I've been struggling to get a traditional Blazor wasm with an api deployed to subdomain, like broodjes.myschool.be, where there is a traditional separate static website on www.myschool.be
The setup of the application to be deployed is a Blazor Wasm project and an API-project linked to a database on a Windows server with IIS.
As many things can go wrong and did, I decided to step back and try first to deploy easier applications, solve potential problems and than move further. The hope was I could avoid that multiple problems popping up at the same time.
My current blocking issue is a CORS-issue, as described below, preventing me from calling on the webAPI.

There is overlap with this topic on SO for sure.. Only that question did never receive a valid answer, the solution proposed was alluding to a subapp, which was not the case for that question, nor for this one. And Blazor Request blocked by CORS policy, neither of them provided me with answers.

The first step was to simply get the counter (Microsoft sample) standalone blazor wasm deployed, in the end, I could solve the issues involved after an upgrade to .net 8.4.
You can find both the code and the deployed files here.
This worked.

For me the next step would be to deploy a Blazor wasm project and an api not yet linked to a database.
[For that I used a public code base linked to a PluralSight course.], (https://github.com/RolandGuijt/ps-carvedrock-aspnetcorebp) authored by Roland Guijt.
To be consistent I upgraded that solution also to .net 8.4, added an open-CORS-policy, added IISSettings in the LaunchSettings.
Running locally the solution works, although on http because of quirks with VS and certificates. Here's the repo of the code
Contrary to other info out there on the web, I decided to deploy the api and the wasm project seperately. Like described by Medhat Elmasry.
In the dns hosts-file (Navigate to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc path) I added the line
127.0.0.1                    warehouse.yourcandystore.com
I also installed the IIS CORS Module and rebooted the server.
After the api-deployment, https://broodjes.myschool.com:7273/product will return the product list in json on local server
.
With a separate deployment with a wasm project that calls on http://localhost:7273/product, I get the following error:
Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:7273/product' from origin 'https://broodjes.myschool.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
Microsoft provides information on how to configure CORS
after trying to define a specific policy like
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options
        .AddPolicy("OpenCorsPolicy", builder =>
            builder
                .WithOrigins("https://localhost:7220", "http://localhost:7220", "https://broodjes.myschool.be")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod());
});


with attributes above the controller. If you would define a defaultpolicy which allows any origin, header or method, i would expect it to pass through
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options
    .AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
            builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()


But i continue to have the same error messages. So I'm kind at a loss here to solve the issue.

The only strategies left are to set up a proxy, but I don't have a feeling that this will be the silver bullet.
And to check the CSP on the web server Content Security Policy
Please advise in solving this issue.
Update
webconfig-file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\CarvedRock-WebApi.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: E7D06A34-3EF1-4CFE-A038-4EB7F14B3168-->

meanwhile the api stopped working
Update
event viewer
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" />
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
  <Level>2</Level>
  <Task>0</Task>
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-05-22T11:09:32.934426200Z" />
  <EventRecordID>4645935</EventRecordID>
  <Channel>Application</Channel>
  <Computer>WIN-SCCG7RAK0CC</Computer>
  <Security />
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer EventId: 2 SpanId: 04c4f1a8de7009f4 TraceId: d6be4ab526b8b8c2269a0a6ae8503fae ParentId: 0000000000000000 RequestId: 80000002-0000-e700-b63f-84710c7967bb RequestPath: /product Connection ID "16645304224371965953", Request ID "80000002-0000-e700-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Endpoint CarvedRock_WebApi.Controllers.ProductController.GetAll (CarvedRock-WebApi) contains CORS metadata, but a middleware was not found that supports CORS. Configure your application startup by adding app.UseCors() in the application startup code. If there are calls to app.UseRouting() and app.UseEndpoints(...), the call to app.UseCors() must go between them. at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.ThrowMissingCorsMiddlewareException(Endpoint endpoint) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()</Data>
  </EventData>
  </Event>

Update
After defining the csp, the error messgae has changed. I get a 200 OK, yet no content.

Update
the api seems to work
wasm gets the data, but fails to process it
enter image description here[][3]
with following error message
blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: net_http_message_not_success_statuscode, 0, 
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: net_http_message_not_success_statuscode, 0, 
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at CarvedRock_BlazorWebAssembly.ApiServices.ProductApiService.GetAll()
   at CarvedRock_BlazorWebAssembly.Pages.Index.OnInitializedAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task , ComponentState )


---

The last step would be the actual deployment of my application.

add AllowCredentials() in your policy

What is your webConfig?

I'll add my WebConfig in the question

Can you give the last error of tne .Net runtime in the event viewer?

I'll add it on the bottom of the question.

reactivate app.UseCors(); in the program.cs without policy and redeploy

Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics EventId: 6 Application startup exception Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The CORS protocol does not allow specifying a wildcard (any) origin and credentials at the same time. Configure the CORS policy by listing individual origins if credentials needs to be supported. at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsPolicyBuilder.Build() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsOptions.AddPolicy(String name, Action`1 configurePolicy)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsOptions.AddDefaultPolicy(Action`1 configurePolicy) at Program.

I'll remove AllowCredentials and deploy again

the api works again and back the old error message in the wasm

let's work on the webconfig. If you have been messing around with source control, you could try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68468597/angular-11-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-r, and apply to adjustment to your webconfig

else exploit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471861/access-to-xmlhttprequest-from-origin-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-no-access

the latter seems redundant. Looks like the configuration you're already doing in program.cs.

no changes  ... .

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77890739/cors-configuration-issue-in-blazor-net-8-application suggests setting the CSP. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP.

something like                                                                                                                           

note that the http:// and the https:// have been removed hy the text editor of stack overflow

I'll get a different error message now, I'll post it in the question.

You should install IIS CORS module and then try again, https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module

I know my explanation is a bit too long, but already did that. It's hidden under the dns file change. But greatly appreciated to share your time and thoughts. I'm a bit further now already, but still not there. I'll add an update on the bottom.

By ensuring correct CORS configuration in both the API and IIS, updating your DNS settings, and deploying your Blazor WASM and API projects separately, you should be able to resolve the CORS issues and successfully deploy your application.
